# The binding of a class using JAXB against a XML element returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am having an issue where the binding of a class against a XML element was not successfully. Instead it returns NullPointerException. Below is the sample XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sh="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:getNumberResponse
            xmlns="http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:cds="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/manageServiceFault/2010/06/Contact/Details"
            xmlns:sh="http://wsi.nat.bt.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06 MSF_5.0.xsd">
            <sh:standardHeader>
                <sh:e2e>
                    <sh:E2EDATA>E2E.graphID=2.1,E2E.from=ORESB,E2E.to=ORautofix,E2E.compTxnName=FaultProcessing,E2E.compTxnID=385h6g8lbh,E2E.busTxnStage=REQ,E2E.busProcID=1-CKMT1EEV,E2E.busProcType=ManageFaultRequests,E2E.busTxnSeq=385h5smgod,E2E.threadID=385h6g8koz,E2E.busTxnSys=AddFault,tradingPartnerId=735380615,E2E.busTxnHdr=PCK002069,E2E.busTxnType=AddFault,E2E.busProcOriginator=ORESB-default,E2E.busTxnUsr=siebel,E2E.busTxnLoc=UNKNOWN,E2E.threadID.4=APP10639:385h6g75io:385h6g8koz,E2E.threadID.3=:385h6fq4wv,E2E.threadID.2=ORSiebel:385h5smh48:385h6fq4wv,E2E.threadID.1=:
                    </sh:E2EDATA>
                </sh:e2e>
                <sh:serviceState>
                    <sh:stateCode>OK</sh:stateCode>
                    <sh:errorCode />
                    <sh:errorDesc />
                    <sh:errorText />
                    <sh:errorTrace />
                </sh:serviceState>
            </sh:standardHeader>
            <actionRequestId />
            <appointment>
                <apptRequired>Y</apptRequired>
                <apptSlot>0</apptSlot>
                <apptType>Type</apptType>
                <apptReference>Reference001</apptReference>
                <earliestApptSlot>1</earliestApptSlot>
                <earliestDate>2015-05-25T01:00:00</earliestDate>
            </appointment>
            <endUserDetails>
                <firstName>Chris</firstName>
                <lastName>Wong</lastName>
                <priTelephone>+60123333333</priTelephone>
                <secTelephone>+60123333334</secTelephone>
                <cssDBID>1234</cssDBID>
            </endUserDetails>
            <serviceAffectingFlag>N</serviceAffectingFlag>
            <number>123456789</number>
            <service>
                <serviceId xsi:nil="false">ONEA20160721_0067</serviceId>
            </service>
            <service>
                <serviceId xsi:nil="false">ONEA20160721_0068</serviceId>
            </service>
        </ns:getNumberResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And below is my of domain class: UserDetail

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "endUserDetails")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDetail {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String priTelephone;
    private String secTelephone;
    private String cssDBID;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPriTelephone() {
        return priTelephone;
    }

    public void setPriTelephone(String priTelephone) {
        this.priTelephone = priTelephone;
    }

    public String getSecTelephone() {
        return secTelephone;
    }

    public void setSecTelephone(String secTelephone) {
        this.secTelephone = secTelephone;
    }

    public String getCssDBID() {
        return cssDBID;
    }

    public void setCssDBID(String cssDBID) {
        this.cssDBID = cssDBID;
    }

}
```

This is Appointment

```
package com.bt.automation.domain;

import java.util.Date;

public class Appointment {

    private String apptRequired;
    private String apptSlot;
    private String apptType;
    private String apptReference;
    private String earliestApptSlot;

    private Date earliestDate;

    public String getApptRequired() {
        return apptRequired;
    }

    public void setApptRequired(String apptRequired) {
        this.apptRequired = apptRequired;
    }

    public String getApptSlot() {
        return apptSlot;
    }

    public void setApptSlot(String apptSlot) {
        this.apptSlot = apptSlot;
    }

    public String getApptType() {
        return apptType;
    }

    public void setApptType(String apptType) {
        this.apptType = apptType;
    }

    public String getApptReference() {
        return apptReference;
    }

    public void setApptReference(String apptReference) {
        this.apptReference = apptReference;
    }

    public String getEarliestApptSlot() {
        return earliestApptSlot;
    }

    public void setEarliestApptSlot(String earliestApptSlot) {
        this.earliestApptSlot = earliestApptSlot;
    }

    public Date getEarliestDate() {
        return earliestDate;
    }

    public void setEarliestDate(Date earliestDate) {
        this.earliestDate = earliestDate;
    }

}
```

and lastly another domain class Response

```
package com.bt.automation.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import com.bt.automation.domain.autofix.UserDetail;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Envelope")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    private long number;
    private String actionRequestId;
    private String serviceAffectingFlag;

    private Appointment appointment;
    private UserDetail userDetail;

    private List<MyService> service;

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getActionRequestId() {
        return actionRequestId;
    }

    public void setActionRequestId(String actionRequestId) {
        this.actionRequestId = actionRequestId;
    }

    public String getServiceAffectingFlag() {
        return serviceAffectingFlag;
    }

    public void setServiceAffectingFlag(String serviceAffectingFlag) {
        this.serviceAffectingFlag = serviceAffectingFlag;
    }

    public List<MyService> getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(List<MyService> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Appointment getAppointment() {
        return appointment;
    }

    public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        this.appointment = appointment;
    }

    public UserDetail getUserDetail() {
        return userDetail;
    }

    public void setUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        this.userDetail = userDetail;
    }

}
```

In the code, I would like to bind class UserDetail to XML element endUserDetails. So below is my code

```
 package com.bt.automation.xml;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

import com.bt.automation.domain.Appointment;
import com.bt.automation.domain.MyService;
import com.bt.automation.domain.Response;
import com.bt.automation.domain.autofix.UserDetail;

public class UnmarshalResponse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("response.xml"));
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Envelope tag

        int i = 0;
        while (!xsr.getLocalName().equals("getNumberResponse")) {
            System.out.println(i + xsr.getLocalName());
            xsr.nextTag();

            i = i + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Current element: " + xsr.getLocalName());
        System.out.println("Namespace: " + xsr.getNamespaceContext().getNamespaceURI("ns"));

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Response> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Response.class);
        xsr.close();

        Response response = je.getValue();
        System.out.println("Object: " + response);
        System.out.println("Number: " + response.getNumber());
        System.out.println("Request ID: " + response.getActionRequestId());
        System.out.println("Flag: " + response.getServiceAffectingFlag());

        Appointment app = response.getAppointment();
        System.out.println("Appointment.apptRequired: " + app.getApptRequired());
        System.out.println("Appointment.apptReference: " + app.getApptReference());
        System.out.println("Appointment.apptType: " + app.getApptType());
        System.out.println("Appointment.earliestApptSlot: " + app.getEarliestApptSlot());
        System.out.println("Appointment.apptSlot: " + app.getApptSlot());
        System.out.println("Appointment.earliestDate: " + app.getEarliestDate());

        UserDetail userDetail = response.getUserDetail();
        System.out.println("UserDetail.getFirstName: " + userDetail.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("UserDetail.getLastName: " + userDetail.getLastName());
        System.out.println("UserDetail.getPriTelephone: " + userDetail.getPriTelephone());
        System.out.println("UserDetail.getSecTelephone: " + userDetail.getSecTelephone());
        System.out.println("UserDetail.getCssDBID: " + userDetail.getCssDBID());

        List<MyService> list = response.getService();
        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Service " + i + ": " + response.getService().get(i).getServiceId());
        }
    }

}
```

However, it returns NullPointerException when I run the code. One question here, is it a must that domain class must be the same name with the bound XML element?

Answer (score 0):

You got a `NullPointerException` because `response.getAnnotation()` was `null`. Actually all properties of `response` were `null` because none of the corresponding XML contents was successfully unmarshalled.

The reason is: your Java classes completely ignore XML namespaces.
The namespace in the `ns:getNumberResponse` XML element and all the
sub-elements without namespace-prefix (`appointment`, `endUserDetails`, `service`, ...)
don't match the namespaces in your Java classes.

For learning more about JAXB annotations I suggest to read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html) and the javadoc of package [`javax.xml.bind.annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html) especially of `XmlElement` and `XmlRootElement`.

For solving your problems you have two options:

1. change the XML contents to match your existing Java classes
2. or change the Java classes to match your existing XML content.

The following solution assumes you prefer to change the Java classes and don't change the XML content.

Class `Response`:
In `@XmlRootElement` you need to set the correct `name` and `namespace`.
For all properties you need to set the correct `namespace`.
For property `userDetail` you need to set `name = "endUserDetails"`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getNumberResponse", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private long number;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String actionRequestId;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String serviceAffectingFlag;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private Appointment appointment;

    @XmlElement(name = "endUserDetails", namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private UserDetail userDetail;

    @XmlElement(name = "service", namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private List<MyService> service;

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

Class `Appointment`:
For all properties you need to set the correct `namespace`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Appointment {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String apptRequired;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String apptSlot;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String apptType;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String apptReference;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String earliestApptSlot;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private Date earliestDate;

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

Class `UserDetail`:
For all properties you need to set the correct `namespace`.
You can omit `@XmlRootElement`, because it has no effect in a non-root element.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDetail {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String priTelephone;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String secTelephone;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ccm.intra.bt.com/manageServiceFault/2006/06")
    private String cssDBID;

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

You didn't post your class `MyService`. I assume you need to do similar corrections there, too.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. It works after I added a package level namespace in package-info.java. Regarding to the `@XmlRootElement`, I was not know that it has no effect to the non-root element. So I have removed those.

Comment: @chris Using `@XmlSchema(namespace="...")` in your `package-info.java`
seems to be a great solution. May be then you don't need the many
`namespace="..."` in the classes of this package anymore.

Comment: Hi Thomas, am facing another issue now related to XmlElementWrapper. Are you able to help here? This is the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364754/fails-to-unmarshal-list-of-xml-same-elements-having-same-name-as-parents-element